# xtoolkit - how to move or reposition the progress bar and how to customize it?

Tags: xtk

**[xtk] xtoolkit - how to move or reposition the progress bar and how to customize it ?**

i want to move the progress bar that shows up when loading or rendering ,,,

and also i want to customize it ( colors , size , etc )

is it possible using css ? is there is a class for that progress bar so i can reposition or to customize it ?

any help will be appreciated

and thanks in advance ..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................